# Android Studio OpenCV yolo where do I put my files?

Tags: android, opencv, assets, yolo

I am creating an app in android studio that uses library opencv and yolo. I want to store the yolo config file and weights inside the android package. Right now I have those file in the external storage of my phone and I access them like this:

```
String yoloCfg = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dnns/traffic-yolov3-tiny.cfg" ;
String yoloWeights = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dnns/traffic-yolov3-tiny_15000.weights";
yolo = Dnn.readNetFromDarknet(yoloCfg, yoloWeights);
```

My question is: where do I put yolo config file and weights for them to be inside the app when the user downloads the apk and how do I get the path to them, since readNetFromDarknet needs as args the path of those files.

I have tried put them in the asset and attempt to get the path to asset but it doesnt work. This is the code I tried:

```
String yoloCfg = "file:///android_asset/traffic-yolov3-tiny.cfg";
String yoloWeights = "file:///android_asset/traffic-yolov3-tiny_15000.weights";
yolo = Dnn.readNetFromDarknet(yoloCfg, yoloWeights);
```

This is where I have the files:
[Location of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQzYh.jpg)

And this is the error I get:

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV(4.0.1) Error: Parsing error (Failed to parse NetParameter file: file:///android_asset/traffic-yolov3-tiny.cfg) in readNetFromDarknet, file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_importer.cpp, line 207
E/org.opencv.dnn: dnn::readNetFromDarknet_10() caught cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.1) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_importer.cpp:207: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter file: file:///android_asset/traffic-yolov3-tiny.cfg in function 'readNetFromDarknet'
E/SurfaceView: Exception configuring surface
```

Comment: Of course you should put them in assets.

Comment: and how do I get the PATH of assets? Because I have tried to get it and there is an error.

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: Done. I edit the question

Comment: You cannot use something like file:///android_asset/.... as that is something only a webview understands. Instead you call the assets manager and then open an input stream for your file. Then read from the stream. The stream is read only.

Comment: I don´t want an input stream because I don't want to read what is inside of the files. The readNetFromDarknet method accepts only a PATH to the files

Comment: Use that inputstream to copy the contents of the file to the file system. Then use the path of the copy.

Comment: Where do I put the new file and how do I get the path?

Comment: Put it at getFilesDir(). `File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "myfile.txt"); String path = file.getAbsolutePath(); Log.d("path: ", path);`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. What I did to fix this was to add the files in the asset folder; then I created two files and copied the content of the asset folder files there.

Make sure to use the following path and create your files there:

```
applicationContext.filesDir.absolutePath
```